# Simplest way to get type in C for debugging purposes

Tags: c

Usually when I need the type in C for something I don't know I'll just print it with a wrong format and see what `gcc` tells me. For example:

```
int printme(int n, ...)
{
    // What type is `va_list` ??
    va_list ap;
    printf("%d", ap);
}

int main(void)
{
    printme("Hi", "There");
}
```

```
 > a.c:12:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, 
    but argument 2 has type ‘__va_list_tag *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%d", ap);
```

Is there a better way to inspect the type of something for debugging purposes?

Comment: You could use the `typeof` macro maybe, and use `_Generic`s to handle each type. [`typeof` guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) and [`_Generic` guide](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html). I'm not sure if this will allow you to print the type though, unless you handle every possible type with the `_Generic`

Comment: "*for debugging purposes*" The debugger itself would normally tell you the type of variables involved. Depending on environment, the editor or IDE might have options to navigate to the definitions and types.

Comment: I wonder why you don't know the type of your object of interest. C is a quite strongly typed language. Do you have an example where you cannot know the type? -- In your example the type of `ap` is clear, it is a `va_list`. Apparently this is a `typedef`ed type, which actually is `__va_list_tag*`. And how does this help you?

Comment: @thebusybee yea I mean basically what some of the built-in macros or typedefs are. For example, answering the question, "Ok, yes it is of type `va_list`, but what does that mean? What is that type built of?" Same with something like the `FILE` type where it is a complex-ish structure. Perhaps seeing what that struct is composed of.

Comment: @carl.hiass Both `va_list` and `FILE` are *opaque* pointers precisely because what hides behind them is an implementation detail which you are not supposed to care about. That said, most implementations provide the CRT sources, where you can find the internal details.

Comment: You mean something like ... `strstr(..` hmmm ... is the needle first or the haystack??? I don't really want to go check on the man page or internet... I'll just compile `strstr(3.1416)` and check the compiler message? ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way, and I'd say, it is the only *Right Thing(TM)* to do:

**Read the source defining the data type.**

Generally, C has no way to tell you during run time, what type a value has. Other languages have "reflection" or a similar feature, but not C.

To simplify this task, you might like to use a tool that reads all source files and header files of your project, and that gives you an overview. However, software recommendations are out of scope of this site.

Comment: Thanks, out of curiosity, what would be an example of a tool that gives an overview? Something like `ctags` or is this something else?

Comment: It depends heavily on the time you like to spend evaluating such tools, the time you like to spend to learn the tool, the time you like to spend to make the tool to know your project, the information you like to obtain, and so no. That's why we don't recommend software. You need to do your own research and evaluation, based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Type of `va_list` is a compiler implementation defined type. Basically is a type necessary to be able to do the following, when used with these macros:

```
void f(int a, int b, double fmt, ...)
{
    va_list p;

    va_start(p, fmt);  /* save the address in the stack of parameter `fmt` */
    ....
    SOME_TYPE q = va_arg(p, SOME_TYPE);
    ....
    SOME_TYPE q = va_arg(p, SOME_TYPE);
    ....
    va_end(p);
}
```

which is how the thing is prepared to work.
Old implementations used a `void *[1]` type (an array of one pointer to void element --- or even a `char *[]` pointer, in very old implementations) to store there the reference to the first parameter, which was moved by the `sizeof (SOME_TYPE)` when `va_arg` macro was called  (`SOME_TYPE` is not restricted to be always the same type, you can change the type in each call to `va_arg`).  But today, it is normally implemented as some intrinsic function of the compiler, as some knowledge of how the stack is incremented/decremented or how the compiler handlers register passed parameters is necessary to implement it.

If you don't get so complex, and you have to know e.g. how the type `dev_t` is defined (this is a posix type, not an ansi-c type, because it is the type that a posix type uses to represent a device in the kernel)  and you need to print it, then you can always cast it to an `int` (or a `long`) and use that in your `printf` format.

Historically there have been some approaches to this (like using `z` modifier in the format string to print a `size_t` or `ssize_t` data type)  but not every compiler has them implemented and this force you to stick on one of the last standards.  If you want to produce portable code, the casting mechanism is probably the best, if you know *a priori* that the value is going to fit in the type you use to print.